# Discrete Summation transformation

Tags: summation

Tried to prove this by writing out as I hoped the e terms would simplify, but it wasn't the case so I am stuck now. Am I missing a summation property I could use?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{n=5}(\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-i2\pi k}{6}})^n =
\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-i2\pi k}{6}})^6 }{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-i2\pi k}{6}} } $$

Hints and/or solutions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a geometric sum.
$$S_n =1+r+ r^2+\cdots + r^n$$

$$rS_n =r+ r^2+ r^3+\cdots + r^{n+1}$$
Subtracting, most terms cancel and you get
$$(1-r)S_n=(1+r+ r^2+\cdots + r^n)-(r+ r^2+ r^3+\cdots + r^{n+1})$$
$$(1-r)S_n=1-r^{n+1}$$
If $r\neq 1$, then
$$S_n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Is this what you want to show?